# How to pass integer or boolean value to params and JSON through Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com and parse_resource to connect my Rails app to Parse.com. I have a Post object with properties "Score" (Integer) and "Name" (String). But when I try to create a new Post object on Rails and use a standard HTML form like:

```
<%= f.label :score %><br />  
<%= f.text_field :score %>
```

the "Score" property just gets passed as a "String" on Parse.com. I want it to be passed as Integer/Number.

How can I make this :score show up as Integer/Number value? I'm guessing this has to do with how the JSON reads the parameters but not sure how to manipulate the JSON.

My PostController's create action:

```
  def create
    @post= Post.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, I thought doing this would solve the problem.

```
def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.score = post_params[:score].to_i
```

And it almost did, as it sent score as a "Number" to Parse.com. However, it showed up as 0, which meant that it was quietly failing somewhere.

Fixing strong params in the bottom of the controller solved the problem.
Originally it looked like this

```
def post_params
  params[:post]
end
```

After proper settings (I Fixed it to below)

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:name, :bodyText, :score)
end
```